# WPF C# LINQ: Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string' query

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq

I'm trying to execute this query but for some reason it doesn't like the fact that 2 strings are sitting beside each other, here's the query:

```
var FiveSecStatsQuery = from qai in connection.QuickAnalyzerInputs
                             join calP in connection.CalculatedPrices on qai.InputID equals calP.TradeID
                             where ***(qai.ClientName = clientName) && (qai.CurrencyPair = cur_pair)*** 
                             && (calP.Description = PriceDescriptions.FiveSeconds) && (calP.Outcome != null)
                             select new
                             {
                                 calP.Outcome
                             };
```

The error is : Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Why is it giving me this error? Both ClientName and CurrencyPair are of type string in the database. The error occurs where the asterisks are

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need double `==`, not single `=` so your `where` clause should be:

```
where (qai.ClientName == clientName) && (qai.CurrencyPair == cur_pair)
&& (calP.Description == PriceDescriptions.FiveSeconds) && (calP.Outcome != null)
```

Comment: Wowww! thanks been staring at it for 15 min and I couldn't see that. Thanks again @Habib!

Comment: `Where(m=> (m.zdjh == msn).ToString() && (dt >= m.sjsj).ToString()` this is my LINQ exp and I am getting `operator && cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string' c#`

Answer (score 4):

Change `(qai.ClientName = clientName) && (qai.CurrencyPair = cur_pair)` to `(qai.ClientName == clientName) && (qai.CurrencyPair == cur_pair)`
since its boolean operation not value assignment